# Does rake routes show all of my applications available routes or are some missing in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I would like to know if my route clash is expected:

I have a photo albums page which is a dedicated area for my users to create photo albums to store their photos in located at:

**http://localhost:3000/settings/photo_gallery**

From this page my users can create new albums or click on existing ones. When they click on existing albums in order to add photos to them they are taken to this page:

**http://localhost:3000/settings/photo_gallery/:id**

Now I have set up these 2 routes:

```
  resources :photo_albums, :path => "/settings/photo_gallery"
  resources :photos, :path => "/settings/photo_gallery/photos"
```

When a user clicks add photo the page they see is located at:

**http://localhost:3000/settings/photo_gallery/photos/new**

So I'm wanting to link to this page from the page with an add a photo link on it, I need to add the correct path or url link to the link_to helper method.

I've checked rake routes and I can't really understand how to translate this particular route because photo_album seems to be representing more than 1 route and I'm becoming confused.

Here is my rake routes code:

```
  users GET    /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                      POST   /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
             new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
            edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                      PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                      DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
             sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"sessions"}
                      POST   /sessions(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
          new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
         edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"sessions"}
              session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sessions"}
                      PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"sessions"}
                      DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
            passwords GET    /passwords(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"passwords"}
                      POST   /passwords(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"passwords"}
         new_password GET    /passwords/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}
        edit_password GET    /passwords/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"passwords"}
             password GET    /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"passwords"}
                      PUT    /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"passwords"}
                      DELETE /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"passwords"}
             profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"profiles"}
                      POST   /profiles(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"profiles"}
          new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"profiles"}
         edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
              profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
                      PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}
                      DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"profiles"}
               emails GET    /emails(.:format)                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"emails"}
                      POST   /emails(.:format)                                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"emails"}
            new_email GET    /emails/new(.:format)                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"emails"}
           edit_email GET    /emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"emails"}
                email GET    /emails/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"emails"}
                      PUT    /emails/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"emails"}
                      DELETE /emails/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"emails"}
               photos GET    /photos(.:format)                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                      POST   /photos(.:format)                                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
            new_photo GET    /photos/new(.:format)                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
           edit_photo GET    /photos/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
                photo GET    /photos/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                      PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                      DELETE /photos/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
                 root        /                                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
              success        /success(.:format)                                {:action=>"success", :controller=>"users"}
                login        /login(.:format)                                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
               logout        /logout(.:format)                                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
       reset_password        /reset_password(.:format)                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}
   setup_new_password        /setup_new_password(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"passwords"}
             settings        /settings(.:format)                               {:action=>"settings", :controller=>"users"}
     settings_account        /settings/account(.:format)                       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"account"}
settings_edit_profile        /settings/edit_profile(.:format)                  {:controller=>"profiles", :action=>"edit_profile"}
                             /:username(.:format)                              {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
      change_password        /change_password(.:format)                        {:action=>"change_password", :controller=>"users"}
         photo_albums GET    /settings/photo_gallery(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                      POST   /settings/photo_gallery(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
      new_photo_album GET    /settings/photo_gallery/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
     edit_photo_album GET    /settings/photo_gallery/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
          photo_album GET    /settings/photo_gallery/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                      PUT    /settings/photo_gallery/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                      DELETE /settings/photo_gallery/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photo_albums"}
                      GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                      POST   /settings/photo_gallery/photos(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
                      GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
                      GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
                      GET    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                      PUT    /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                      DELETE /settings/photo_gallery/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
```

The rest of my routes file:

```
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :passwords
  resources :profiles
  resources :emails


  resources :photos


  root :to                   => "users#new"
  match 'success'            => "users#success"
  match 'login'              => "sessions#new"
  match 'logout'             => "sessions#destroy"
  match 'reset_password'     => "passwords#new"
  match 'setup_new_password' => "passwords#edit"
  match 'settings', :to      => "users#settings"


  match "/settings/account", :to => "users#account"
  match "/settings/edit_profile", :to => "profiles#edit_profile"


  match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'

  match 'change_password'    => "users#change_password"

  resources :photo_albums, :path => "/settings/photo_gallery"
  resources :photos, :path => "/settings/photo_gallery/photos"
```

I would really appreciate a helping hand here, I'm sure theres a way to interpret this correctly.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined resources :photos 2 times in your route file. Do you want the earlier( I hope generated by scaffold the plain 'resources :photos') .

1) If you do not need this route you can comment it. That way you don't get ambiguous routes for photos.

2) Move the resources :photos to down so that the routes are still there but your new definition can get you( resources :photos, :path => "/settings/photo_gallery/photos") the path.

3) I would suggest either remove as described in (1) or name the old plain resource as something else like resources :photos, :as => test_photos

Comment: Great thanks, I added that earlier photos route previously and forgot to remove it. That was the problem. Thanks